# Make a web request after receiving a push notification

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2

I have a Swift 2 iOS8+ app where I need to make a request to fetch JSON data when my app receives a push notification.

When the user clicks on the notification the app will go and fetch the data but I really need the data to be fetched as soon as the notification is received.  This looks to be possible, is this the case?

I've implemented:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)){
```

and checking the launch options in:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

I've also enabled:

```
background fetch
remote notifications
```

None of this seems to help.  If this is possible I'd be grateful for any pointers/tutorials on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9, instead of a normal push, you can use silent push notifications. When your app receives a silent push, the user is not notified, but your app can perform actions based on this notification. Then, when your background actions is finished, you create a local notification for the user.

Check out this tutorial for info on how to use silent notifications:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial